# kafka zookeeper /consumers/group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am having real trouble understanding where /consumers/group comes from.  I have 2 Kafka clusters which I am replicating utilizing mirror-maker.  The replication works fine, but there is piece that is eluding me.

When I am pulling messages from Kafka (in this case utilizing python) I am seeing that replication works fine.

However I am seeing nothing in zookeeper /consumers/group and thereby I can't test it with "bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker "

(It is saying that Exiting due to: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-group/offsets/)

Environment
Kafka 2_8
OS Ubuntu 14.4
Zookeeper 3.4.5

OK I got further along.  The issue it seems is that mirror maker isn't creating a group id.  When I create the group id from within kafka tool I can view everything.  Therefore only question left is why mirror maker wouldn't be creating a group id.

Comment: Are you using the built in mirror maker? and what kafka version is it?

Comment: Yes I am, and version is: 2.10-0.8.2.1

Comment: hey, me too facing the same problem..did you get solution to it?